# need to split tab delimited text into multiple variables in linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I need to split a line into multiple variables within single line of command. 
I need to fetch each field between tabs into a separate variable.  For example:

```
000345AA6| |N|20150410|A & M FRNT 3/01/17|
```

I'm using awk to fetch each field and then `eval` to export variable to shell from awk. Since the last field (5th) has a space, I'm getting an error.

Code:

```
z=`echo "000380105| |%|20150410|ABCAM PLC ADR |" | awk -F "|" '{print "SOURCE_FIELD2="$2;SOURCE_FIELD3=$3;print "SOURCE_FIELD4="$4;SOURCE_FIELD5=$5;}'`
eval "$z"
echo $SOURCE_FIELD4
```

Actual Output:

```
test.ksh[12]: PLC:  not found
```

Expected:

```
ABCAM PLC ADR
```

I have 19 fields in the line and want to assign variables with good performance. Using the `cut` command is taking too long as I need to do this for about 130k lines.

Comment: Thanks for formatting the post.

Answer (score 3):

Use `IFS=delim read -a array` to read the fields into an array, splitting on the character(s) in `$IFS`.

```
while IFS='|' read -r -a fields; do
    printf '[%s]\n' "${fields[@]}"

    echo "${fields[0]}"
    echo "${fields[1]}"
    ...
done < file.txt
```

Comment: If you want to use named variables, `IFS='|' read -r varA varB varC etc`